# Добавить итоговую строку в результат запроса TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть динамически составляемый запрос, т.е. число полей в нем варьируется. В каждом из динамических полей предcтает `float` значение. Сам запрос выдает результат нарастающим итогом в каждом поле. Последняя строка должна быть итоговой и вмещать в себя разницу последней и первой строк каждого из полей. Первое поле фиксировано и имеет "ярлыковую функцию", то есть просто обозначает дату или итог.

Вот так выглядит определение полей:

```
    SELECT
        @CellsFields = @CellsFields + ',' + 
        'ROUND(MAX(CASE WHEN val.ObjectLocationId = '+CONVERT(varchar(10), loc.Id)+' and val.ParametrId = 20 THEN val.VL ELSE 0 END),3) as [' + loc.ShortName+', значение1] '+','+
        'ROUND(MAX(CASE WHEN val.ObjectLocationId = '+CONVERT(varchar(10), loc.Id)+' and val.ParametrId = 22 THEN val.VL ELSE 0 END),3) as [' + loc.ShortName+', значение2] '        
    FROM
        [dbo].[PokazateliBlaBla] loc
    WHERE   
        loc.ObjectId = @ObjectId
```

А вот так вызывается сам запрос:

```
SET @SQL =
    '

    SELECT
        CONVERT(varchar(10),val.TM,104) as ''Дата'''+@CellsFields+'
    FROM
        [dbo].[ValuesBlaBla] val
    WHERE
        val.ParametrID in (20,22) and
        val.TM between '''+@DateStart+' 00:00:00'' and '''+@DateEnd+' 23:59:59''
    GROUP BY
        CONVERT(varchar(10),val.TM,104)
    ORDER BY
        CONVERT(varchar(10),val.TM,104)

    '

    EXEC(@SQL)
```

Результатом будет набор такого вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я разобрался со всем кроме последней строки. Ума уже не приложу как мне получить разницу между первым и последним значениями. Если опираться на картинку, то нужно вычесть значение за `01.09.19` из `30.09.19`. Буду рад любым советам и указаниям на, вероятно, неверный подход к решению.

Comment: *как мне получить разницу между первым и последним значениями.* `FIRST_VALUE(value) OVER (ORDER BY time DESC) - FIRST_VALUE(value) OVER (ORDER BY time ASC)`. Само собой в отдельном CTE.

Comment: @Akina С точки зрения оптимизации обычно лучше `FIRST_VALUE(value) OVER (ORDER BY time DESC) - LAST_VALUE(value) OVER (ORDER BY time DESC)` Две разные сортировки в over() обычно и в плане выполнения приводят к двум отдельным сортировкам

Comment: @Mike Это да. Только для использования LAST_VALUE придётся явно указывать границы окна UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал вот так.
Сперва наплодил обычные поля на пару с итоговыми:

```
SELECT
        @CellsFields = @CellsFields + ',' + 
        'ROUND(MAX(CASE WHEN val.ObjectLocationId = '+CONVERT(varchar(10), loc.Id)+' and val.ParametrId = 20 THEN val.VL ELSE 0 END),3) as [' + loc.ShortName+', значение1] '+','+
        'ROUND(MAX(CASE WHEN val.ObjectLocationId = '+CONVERT(varchar(10), loc.Id)+' and val.ParametrId = 22 THEN val.VL ELSE 0 END),3) as [' + loc.ShortName+', значение2] ',
        @TotalFields = @TotalFields + ',' +
        'ROUND(MAX(CASE WHEN val.ObjectLocationId = '+CONVERT(varchar(10), loc.Id)+' and val.ParametrId = 20 and (val.TM between '''+@DateEnd+' 00:00:00'' and '''+@DateEnd+' 23:59:59'') THEN val.VL ELSE 0 END)-'+
        'MAX(CASE WHEN val.ObjectLocationId = '+CONVERT(varchar(10), loc.Id)+' and val.ParametrId = 20 and (val.TM between '''+@DateStart+' 00:00:00'' and '''+@DateStart+' 23:59:59'') THEN val.VL ELSE 0 END),3) as ''' + loc.ShortName+', значение1'' '+','+
        'ROUND(MAX(CASE WHEN val.ObjectLocationId = '+CONVERT(varchar(10), loc.Id)+' and val.ParametrId = 22 and (val.TM between '''+@DateEnd+' 00:00:00'' and '''+@DateEnd+' 23:59:59'') THEN val.VL ELSE 0 END)-'+
        'MAX(CASE WHEN val.ObjectLocationId = '+CONVERT(varchar(10), loc.Id)+' and val.ParametrId = 22 and (val.TM between '''+@DateStart+' 00:00:00'' and '''+@DateStart+' 23:59:59'') THEN val.VL ELSE 0 END),3) as ''' + loc.ShortName+', значение2'' '       
    FROM
        [Krug].[dbo].[ObjectLocation] loc
    WHERE   
        loc.ObjectId = @ObjectId
```

А потом уже объединил через `UNION ALL` и отсортировал:

```
SET @SQL =
    '
    SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        CONVERT(varchar(10),val.TM,104) as ''Дата'''+@CellsFields+'
    FROM
        [dbo].[ValuesBlaBla] val
    WHERE
        val.ParametrID in (20,22) and
        val.TM between '''+@DateStart+' 00:00:00'' and '''+@DateEnd+' 23:59:59''
    GROUP BY
        CONVERT(varchar(10),val.TM,104)
    UNION ALL    
    SELECT
        ''ИТОГО'' as ''Дата'''+@TotalFields+'
    FROM
        [dbo].[ValuesBlaBla] val
    WHERE
        val.ParametrID in (20,22) and
        val.TM between '''+@DateStart+' 00:00:00'' and '''+@DateEnd+' 23:59:59'') t
    ORDER BY [Дата]
    '

    EXEC(@SQL)
```